# have a list of variables in a do-while loop, but in the while part it errors with "cannot convert '(void)0' to bool

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a do-while loop, using the Do to fill in multiple vectors with the push_back() function, but the While part with all the variables inside returns with an error of "error: could not convert '((void)0, type); from std::string {aka std::basic_string to bool

i tried putting "quoted(location)" but I get a new problem of "quoted is not a declared function" [I was thinking it might be my compiler functions in general, I use cygwin64]

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    double avg(const vector<double>& v){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
            sum+= v.at(i);

        return (1.0 * sum / v.size()); 
         }

    double max(const vector<double>& v) {
        int maxelt = v.at(0);
       for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i) {
            if (v.at(i) < maxelt)
                maxelt = v.at(i);
        }
        return (maxelt);
    }

        void selection_sort(vector<double>&a, vector<double>& b) {
            int max;
            for(int i = 0; i < a.size()-1; i++) {
                max = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < a.size(); j++)
                    if((a.at(j) > a.at(max)) || ((a.at(j) == a.at(max)) && 
    (b.at(j) < b.at(max)))
            )
                    max = j;
            swap(a.at(i), a.at(max));
            swap(b.at(i), b.at(max));
        }
    }


    void print_usage();

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        if (argc != 2) {
            print_usage();
        }

        string junkline;
        unsigned int i;
        vector<string> timeStamps;
        vector<double> latitudes;
        vector<double> longitudes;
        vector<double> depths;
        vector<double> magnitudes;
        vector<string> locations;
        vector<string> types;

        double avgMagnitude;
        double avgDepth;
        string timeStamp;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        double magnitude;
        double depth;
        string location;
        string type;

        getline(cin, junkline);

        do {
            getline(cin, timeStamp);
            timeStamps.push_back(timeStamp);
            cin >> latitude;
            latitudes.push_back(latitude);
            cin >> longitude;
            longitudes.push_back(longitude);
            cin >> magnitude;
            magnitudes.push_back(magnitude);
            cin >> depth;
            depths.push_back(depth);
            getline(cin, quoted(location));
            locations.push_back(location);
            getline(cin, type);
            types.push_back(type);
        }
        while (timeStamp, latitude, longitude, magnitude, depth, location, 
    type);

        avgMagnitude = avg(magnitudes);
        avgDepth = avg(depths);

        cout << "The average magnitude: " << avgMagnitude << endl;
        cout << "The average depth: " << avgDepth << endl;

        selection_sort(longitudes, latitudes);



        ofstream new_all_month;
        new_all_month.open ("sorted data.csv");
        new_all_month << "Timestamp, latitude, longitude, magnitude, 
    depth, location, type" << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < timeStamps.size(); i++) {
            new_all_month << timeStamps.at(i) << "," << latitudes.at(i) << 
    "," << longitudes.at(i) << "," << magnitudes.at(i) << "," << 
     depths.at(i) << "," << locations.at(i) << "," << types.at(i) << endl;
        }
        new_all_month.close();


    return 0;
    }
```

I expect it all to compile iss all. I'm sorting a textfile full of data with this code.

EDIT:: i included the whole code, all functions and the sort.

Comment: the `while (...)` part is for a conditional to determine when to stop looping, I'm not sure what you're trying to do here

Comment: "have a list of variables in a do-while loop". And what would that list mean?

Comment: where and how those variables are defined (e.g.: timeStamp, latitude, etc ...)? can you show us the smallest amount of code, self-consistent, please?

Comment: In `do { ... } while (blah)`, the `blah` is a single expression. What you have might be valid with the right declarations, but it's a comma expression, evaluating and discarding the values of all but the last expression. Assuming it's valid, it's equivalent to just `do { ... } while (type);`. I can tell that's not what you meant, but I can't tell what you did mean.

Comment: `int a = b, c, d;` a equals b. So the *while* condition here is equivalent to `while (timeStamp)`. If you want *and*, use `&&`

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

1. It doesn't compile because strings are not convertible to `bool`. In the expression `while (timeStamp, latitude, longitude, magnitude, depth, location, type)` the compiler is trying to turn strings such as `timeStamp` to `bool`, which fails.  Try `!timeStamp.empty()` or some other boolean expression.
2. Your `while` expression isn't doing what you probably intend.  If you write `while(a, b)`, only `b` participates in the conditional.  You probably want to use &&, like `while (a && b)`.

Comment: `while(a, b)` after testing with gcc, only `a` participates in the conditional. But right, the is not a proper for doing what we want.

Comment: Undefined behaviour after more tests. Depends on compiler.

Comment: @Sandburg I believe this is defined behavior.  GCC will also only look at `b` for `while(a,b)`.  Have a look here for an example: https://godbolt.org/z/ohlDar